# jquery multiple tab navigations on 1 page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have multiple tab navigations on 1 html page and when I click on one navigation it effects the other tab navigations.

I cant seem to figure out how to just effect the tab navigation that I am clicking without hiding the content of other tab navigations.

here is my jquery code

```
// thumbs click
                $('.tabsNav li a').click(function(){
                    $('.tab').hide();
                    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
                    return false;
                });
```

heres my html that I want use multiple times on the page

```
<div class="rightContent">
                    <ul class="tabsNav clearfix">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#vlogs">vlogs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#miniDocs">mini-docs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#trailers">trailers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="vlogs" class="tab">

                    </div>
                    <div id="miniDocs" class="tab">

                    </div>
                    <div id="trailers" class="tab">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What you would want is something along the lines of `$(currenttabselector+' .tab').hide();`, but a lot more context would be necessary to help.

Comment: how would you recommend expanding it?

Comment: my jquery is quite basic, i.e to the standard above

Comment: The problem is that I can't imagine exactly how your tab structure even looks in your DOM. Do you have various tabs with each it's own navigation, or do you have tabs within tabs, or do you have various sets of tabs on a single page or what :S

Comment: ah cheers, i have just added the html

Comment: And you have that on your page only once or multiple times? Because if you have it once it should work o.O .

Comment: i have it multiple times, it works fine when its on its just once

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a div like the rightContent around it (or anything else), this should work:

```
$('.tabsNav li a').click(function(){
   $(this).parents('tabsNav').parent().find('.tab').hide();
   $($(this).attr('href')).show();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tabsNav li a').click(function(){
                   $(this).parents('.tabsNav').parents('.rightContent').children('.tab').hide();
                   $($(this).attr('href')).show();
                   return false;
                });
```

Comment: Why did you repost virtually the same answer I posted? + the `.rightContent` class is probably not the same for every tab navigation (and rather is the container) + find can be optimized inside jquery whilst children can not.